# Selinux is blocking clamd to open new ports for each Thread

Tags: centos, security, selinux, clamav

SElinux Enforced on CentOS7 is blocking again clamAV on scanning file operations.

Some months ago, I encountered the same issue which I [posted here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/372783/selinux-looking-for-some-policy-that-is-blocking-clamd-to-open-new-ports-for-e), which at the end I solved doing the following configurations:

```
# grep 'StreamMin\|StreamMax' /etc/clamd.d/scan.conf
StreamMaxLength 2000M
StreamMinPort 30000
StreamMaxPort 32000
```

---

```
# getsebool -a | grep antivirus
antivirus_can_scan_system --> on
antivirus_use_jit --> on
```

---

```
# semanage port -l | grep clamd
clamd_port_t                   tcp      30000-32000, 3310
```

Yesterday the system got its yum updates, and between them, I see that `selinux-policy*` packages was updated too:

```
Updated     selinux-policy-3.13.1-102.el7_3.16.noarch                @updates
Update                     3.13.1-166.el7_4.4.noarch                 @updates
Updated     selinux-policy-targeted-3.13.1-102.el7_3.16.noarch       @updates
Update                              3.13.1-166.el7_4.4.noarch        @updates
```

After the update the same issue is back as shown in `/var/log/messages`:

```
Sep 15 10:55:45 production clamd: LibClamAV Warning: RWX mapping denied: Can't allocate RWX Memory: Permission denied
Sep 15 10:55:45 production clamd: LibClamAV Warning: Bytecode: disabling JIT because SELinux is preventing 'execmem' access.
Sep 15 10:55:45 production clamd: Run  'setsebool -P clamd_use_jit on'.
```

The log seems pretty clear and offers a solution too, but anyway, this boolean was already set to true previously, so its not that helpful as it seems.

The following is the related `audit.log` entry:

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1505723879.248:302432): avc:  denied  { name_connect } for  pid=21691 comm="java" dest=3310 scontext=system_u:system_r:tomcat_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:clamd_port_t:s0 tclass=tcp_socket
```

Again, the following bugs seems to be related to my issue:

- https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1248785
- https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=573191

But reading them I don't really understand how I could fix it.

I would like to stick with packages updates provided by official CentOS repositories, so I would avoid to roll back the just applied updates (pasted above). Additionally, I would like to keep SElinux in enforced mode.

Any [eyedea](https://rhymesayers.com/artists/eyedea) how to proceed to debug and fix the issue?

Comment: Are you sure the port min and max are still the same? Are you sure the ports are still allowed by selinux? I expect the update wouldn't touch an `/etc/` file, but the selinux ports might have been. It's unclear if those commands were run before or after you started having problems.

Comment: Are you sure you provided the correct AVC message here? I'm not familiar with the policy specifics, but `scontext=system_u:system_r:tomcat_t:s0` doesn't sound correct for ClamAV.

Comment: Thank you guys for the comments, @Centimane: The commands to get configurations was performed after the problems came back -> after selinux update.

Comment: @sebasth: Thank you for the feedback, I may have copied the wrong entry, I performed again a test, and I updated the related content of the post, You made me notice that effectively the audit.log entry is different than the previous issue I had, It look more as tomcat -> clamd communication issue. the port 3310 is used by clamd main service, and please note the `tcontext=system_u:object_r:clamd_port_t:s0 tclass=tcp_socket`

Comment: @lese a process in `tomcat_t` context tries to connect to port with `clamd_port_t` context. You should verify that all processes run in correct contexts (using `ps Z` etc). Have you checked what [`audit2allow`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/audit2allow) tells (specifically if there is a boolean you can enable)?